# address field not displaying value

Tags: iphone

address field is not attaining its value from webservice although name is displaying.
i am using ABPersonViewController to give look as address book have.

```
NSString *strAddress = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:aBook.Address];
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty,strAddress, NULL);
```

help!!

modified code:

```
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [addressDictionary setObject:strAddress forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, addressDictionary, kABHomeLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress, NULL);
        CFRelease(multiAddress);
```

Comment: Add this - make sure you are getting a value - NSLog(@" strAddress is %@", strAddress);

Comment: @mike its working now m updating the above code!!!